# How to pass value from Controller to View (Just In Time/Async)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My Controller/Method has While loop with progress of reading going on and at each step I want to show that progress in View.

I'm calling function with While loop in different Thread but once return state happens
I'm getting error: 'Cannot access a closed file.' - because file closes after return.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Convert()
{
  int progress = 0;
  new Thread(delegate () {
    byte[] stream = html.ReadAsBytesAndOutPercent(out progress);
  }).Start();
  if (progress != 100)
  {
    return Json(progress);
  } else {
    ...
  }
}

public static byte[] ReadAsBytesAndOutPercent(this IFormFile file, out int progress)
{
  long totalBytesOfFile = file.Length;
  byte[] byteToRet = new byte[totalBytesOfFile];
  byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

  int totalReadBytes = 0;
  int readBytes;
  progress = 0;
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    var reader = file.OpenReadStream();
    while ((readBytes = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
      ms.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
      totalReadBytes += readBytes;
      progress = (int)((float)totalReadBytes / (float)totalBytesOfFile * 100);
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

On JS side I'm planing to call Controller with Interval every 10 millseconds

```
setInterval(function () {
     $.post(
        "/Home/Convert",
        function (progress) {
          $("#bar").css({ width: progress + "%" });
          $("#label").html(progress + "%");
        }
      );
    },
    10
  );
```

How to achive something like that ? I'm lacking knowledge at this point any article to clear thing up would be appriciated.

Comment: `ReadAsBytesAndOutPercent(out progress)`,it looks like you even not pass file into `ReadAsBytesAndOutPercent`.

Comment: Using this method on file.MyMethod(); with this key word. Check definition public static byte[] ReadAsBytesAndOutPercent(this IFormFile file, out int progress)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET 6 then you can use AsyncEnumerable. Please go through this blog -
https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/09/02/aspnetcore6-async-stream.html